# JavaScript import does not work in a different or same file

Tags: javascript, html

If I import something, then use it, it will not work in a function or without a function for external js but with inline js

for example

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="foo()">Click Me</button>
</body>
<script type="module">
import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
confetti()
</script>
</html>
```

works

but

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="foo()">Click Me</button>
</body>
<script type="module">
import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
function foo(){
confetti()
}
</script>
</html>
```

and

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="foo()">Click Me</button>
</body>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js:

```js
    import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
    function foo() {
        confetti()
    }
```

or script.js:

```js
    import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
        confetti()
```

don't work

Comment: The whole point of modules is to **not create global variables**. Inline event listeners are bad practice anyways, so just stop using those. This is only one of many, many, many reasons to never ever use those.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the problem is with defining the type of the script as `module`, the type module means that you want to import another module in this script.
so the variables and function inside the script of the type `module` are not accessible outside the scope of execution.

the solution is to assign the function to the global scope `window scope`:

```
<script type="module">
  import confetti from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti";
  window.foo = function () {
    confetti();
  };
</script>
```

here is a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-moon-lc4jvw?file=/index.html:165-333)

Comment: The solution is to stop using inline event listeners, not to defeat the purpose of modules by making the module global. The whole point of modules is ***to not pollute the global namespace***.

Comment: @connexo ok make sense, but what is the solution in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Please stop using inline event listeners, which requires global variables and thus defeats the whole purpose of modules.

Instead, use JavaScript to add the listener:

```html
<button id="foo">Click Me</button>
<script type="module">
  import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
  document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', confetti);
</script>
```